# Log4j2 rolling file appenders file name date is delayed

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, log4j2

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-log4j2`, with `log4j-core 2.14.1`.

I created a timer in main for testing, every 20s print log "hello"

I have to create log with date as filename, now I'm testing it with minute.

However, when I've applied below Appenders, the filename work as unexpected, which act like delay 1 minute for the logging file.

Appender:

```
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="FullLogFile" filePattern="${fullLogBasePath}/%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}_${MY_HOST}.log.gz">

            <PatternLayout pattern="${sys:FILE_LOG_PATTERN}" charset="${sys:CHARSET}"/>

            <Policies>
                <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 * * ? * *" evaluateOnStartup="true"/>
            </Policies>

            <DirectWriteRolloverStrategy>
                <Delete basePath="${fullLogBasePath}/" maxDepth="2">
                    <IfFileName glob="*_My-Host-Variable-*.log.gz" />
                    <IfLastModified age="PT60M" />
                </Delete>
            </DirectWriteRolloverStrategy>

        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
```

Sample result: `zcat 2021-08-27-13-52_My-Host-Variable.log.gz`

```
2021-08-27 13:53:12.078  INFO 1 --- [Timer-0] h.c.h.m.SayHello                         : hello
2021-08-27 13:53:32.079  INFO 1 --- [Timer-0] h.c.h.m.SayHello                         : hello
2021-08-27 13:53:52.078  INFO 1 --- [Timer-0] h.c.h.m.SayHello                         : hello
```

What I'm expecting is, filename with 13-52 should contains log with time 13:52:00~13:52:59, but now it's logging 13:53:00~13:53:59.

Is it an expected result with this setting>? How to accomplish as my ideal, with logging correct time>?

edit1: found that someone has same issue with me. ref: [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1185?focusedCommentId=15964923&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-15964923)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After studying a few days, found that my ideal logging can achieve with below changes.

Changes:

- `RollingRandomAccessFile` to `RollingFile`
- `CronTriggeringPolicy` to `TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy`

Not sure if it's bug / conflict in using `RollingRandomAccessFile` with `CronTriggeringPolicy`.

Below is my config for those who facing same issue with me.

```
<RollingFile name="FullLogFile" filePattern="${fullLogBasePath}/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_${MY_HOST}.log.gz">

    <PatternLayout pattern="${sys:FILE_LOG_PATTERN}" charset="${sys:CHARSET}"/>

    <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
    </Policies>

    <DirectWriteRolloverStrategy>
        <Delete basePath="${fullLogBasePath}/" maxDepth="2">
            <IfFileName glob="*_my-host-name-*.log.gz" />
            <!--        delete log after 90 day -->
            <IfLastModified age="P90D" />
        </Delete>
    </DirectWriteRolloverStrategy>

</RollingFile>
```